# Angular 2 - Validation

Tags: angular

Issues with Ang2 Validation for Reactive Forms.

Tried these ones - but no luck...

here's the code....

Need help on this....
Reactive Forms Validation - validating the FormArray elements...

```html
<input class="form-control g-remove-margin-bottom" value="" type="text" formControlName="myName"   required>
<div *ngIf="myForm.controls['myName'].hasError('required') && myForm.controls['myName'].touched" class="alert alert-danger">
Please enter  form name
</div>
            
   
SomeAcct is the formArray in the DOM  like... <div class="row"  formArrayName="SomeAcct">......</div> 
<input class="form-control g-remove-margin-bottom" value="" type="text" formControlName="myAcct"   required>
<div *ngIf="myForm.controls.SomeAcct.controls.['myAcct'].hasError('required') && myForm.controls.SomeAcct.controls.['myAcct'].touched" class="alert alert-danger">
Please enter Acct Num
</div>

Used this one too in the markup 
<input class="form-control g-remove-margin-bottom" value="" type="text" formControlName="myAcct"   required>
<div *ngIf="myForm.get('SomeAcct').get('myAcct').touched " class="alert alert-danger">Please enter Acct Number</div>
```

SomeAcct is the formArray in the DOM     like... ......

Please enter Acct Num

Used this one too in the markup

Please enter Acct Number

Comment: add your component class in the question.

Comment: You have to specify the index of the control that you want in `FormArray`, because of course, it's an array. Take a look on [**this tutorial**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2).